# precedence of chained assignments and implicit conversions

Tags: c

I've got a simple and stupid code snippet to analyse.
In essence it performs something like:

```
a = b = c;
```

But the types are very tricky.
In one place I have:

```
int a,c;
unsigned int b;
```

In the other place I have:

```
int a;
unsigned int b,c;
```

If the compiler interprets a = b, then I convert an unsigned int to an int
OK, on 2-complement, no matter, such conversion is a no-op
But such conversion can overflow, which would be UB, is it right?
And in this case, the compiler has a license to presume I don't rely on UB, and can thus eventually consider that a>=0 unconditionnally and eliminate a further test `if(a<0) blah...` is it still right?

In such case both pieces of code will result in same behavior though.

If compiler interprets `a = c` and I think that's what is does, and if my above UB analysis is correct, then the two piece of codes could give different results.

So how are these expression interpreted `a=b` or `a=c`, or in other words in which case can such a `(a<0)` branch be eliminated, only one, both or none?

Last note, my exact case is a return value in an inlined function, but I think it would not change above conclusions, right?

```
static inline int a1(unsigned int *b,unsigned int c) {return *b=c;}
static inline int a2(unsigned int *b,int c) {return *b=c;}
```

Comment: 1. There are no casts in the code. 2. The functions you posted don't do anything else than throwing syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = b = c;
```

is same as

```
a = (b = c);
```

which is valid in your two examples.

*But such cast can overflow, which would be UB, is it right?*

There is no cast, but an implicit conversion from one type to another. 
When converting a value of type `unsigned int` to `int`, if the `unsigned int` value is not representable in an `int`, the result of the conversion is either implementation-defined or a implementation-defined behavior signal is raised. Strictly speaking this is still not an overflow and this is not undefined behavior.

Comment: It's possible that this can raise a signed integer overflow exception. Most CPUs won't do this, though.

Comment: you mean that `int a=1U+(unsigned int)(INT_MAX);` is always well defined and that no compiler will ever eliminate following `if(a<0)`?

Comment: @Loadmaster let me rephrase this

Comment: @aka.nice C says either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised in this case. See my edit.

Comment: @ouah OK got it, implementation defined!=undefined, and in most case, it's defined as no-op. For the sake of completeness, do you confirm that the type of (b=c) is the type of b?

Comment: @aka.nice in your two examples the type of `(b=c)` is the type of `b`, yes.